# Can we Create Dynamic Function name and call it in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Hi i am beginner in angular js. I want to know is it possible to give a select box a dynamic ng-change name. As in my case there are multiple select box getting create using ng-repeat and with same ng-change method name so, when i click on one select box it effects on the other select box which should not happen.

i m looking at something like this

```
<div  ng-repeat="country in selectCountryList track by $index" >
<select ng-change="formulaSelect{{index}}()" ng-model="filterCondition.operator" ng-options="operator.value as operator.displayName for operator in formulaType" ></select>
</div>
</div>
```

here is some part of my js file

```
$scope.formulaType = [{value: 'single', displayName: 'Single Formula'},
                        {value: 'double', displayName: 'double Formula'}]
    $scope.filterCondition={ operator: 'double' };
    $scope.countryList =  ["AUS","BEL","BUL","CZE","FRA","GER","HOL","HUN"];

    $scope.formulaSelect<how to write this function> = function(){
    }
```

is it possible like my above code.
if yes than how to perform action on it

Thanks

Comment: can u post formulaSelect function code ?

Comment: you want change a "sub select" if change the parent "select"???

Comment: @marjes: ya thats what i want as the select is getting created dynamically

Comment: what formulaSelect function should does ?

Comment: @shoaib, please do not forget to check the box that helped you

Comment: @levi : the formulaSelect function change the formulatType (single, double) which change the panel in the particular container so, in another container the change should not reflect